# REST api : SELECT statement - how to give alias name to column

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-rest-api

am quite new to REST API.

Below is my select query using REST API

```
http://dummyserver/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('LstEmp')/Items/?$select=EmpNo,Name,EmpNo
```

I want to put an alias name for the 2nd time written EmpNo column. As it is possible in normal SQL Select Statements

```
SELECT EmpNo,Name,EmpNo AS DummyName FROM Emp
```

Have been googling around for this. But didn't found any thing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: why and where you want to use the alias name can you brief it

Answer (score 2):

It does not support the alias name for $select in REST API.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/use-odata-query-operations-in-sharepoint-rest-requests[enter link description here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/use-odata-query-operations-in-sharepoint-rest-requests)

Comment: Hi LZ.Love thank you for detailing this. Is there any alternative way workaround such that we get the list data for a column with an alias name...

Comment: As a workaround, we can use an array to store the alias name map. Like this:
{"DummyName":"EmpNo"}. Then pass the parameters base on the alias name in your code.